# bibliography for The Measure Problem

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I am taking an introductory course to Set Theory and I am supposed to elaborate a project about The Measure Problem, but the problem is that I do not have enough bibliography, actually the only book where I know it is discussed is in "Introduction to Set Theory by Hrbacek and Jech"

is there any other book\article where I can find additional information about this topic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those of us who haven't read that specific book, could you elaborate on what exactly "The Measure Problem" is?

Comment: briefly, if there exist any $\sigma - additive$ measure on $P(\mathbb{R})$ whose measure only have finite values

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "An Introduction to Measure Theory" by Terence Tao, Graduate Studies in Mathematics Vol 126, AMS.

The prologue of Chapter 1 (Section 1.1) is a great exposition on "the problem of measure".

Is this the measure problem that your text refers to?